# django - UNIQUE constraint failed: one_file.user_id

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite

I am making a website in which user can upload files and those files are displayed in user's profile. I had displayed a file in user's profile but when I add 2nd file, it gives an error as:

> IntegrityError at /profile
>
> UNIQUE constraint failed: one_file.user_id

models.py:

```
class file(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=6000)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('one:user')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py:

```
def profile(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        name= request.user.username
        form_class = file_form
        template_name = 'one/profile.html'
        content = file.objects.all()
        if request.method=='GET':
            form = form_class(None)
            return render(request,template_name,{'form':form,'name':name, 'content':content})
        elif request.method=='POST':
            form = form_class(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                FILE = form.save(commit = False)
                FILE.user = request.user
                FILE.save()  
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile')
```

tempalte:

```
logged in as: {{name}}
<br>
<a href="/logout">logout</a>
<br>
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% include 'one/form-template.html' %}
    <button type="submit">
        add file
    </button>
</form>
<br>
<h3>my files</h3>
{% for files in content %}
<p>{{files.title}}</p>
<br>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: you've defined your model such that only one file can be mapped to one user.  that's what a one to one field does.  If you want otherwise, make it a foreign key.

Comment: oh ! that was a silly one.. thanks alot